# How to apply a .fillna() to a filtered dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning pandas using a dataset of players from the womans world cup.

I want to apply a .fillna() on the results of the following filter of the main dataframe:

```
df[(df["pos"] == "GK") & (df["goals"].isnull())]
```

How can I apply:

```
fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

To the above filter, , on the 'goals' column.

I did use the below code but when I apply it, it runs but doesn't seem to work:

```
df.loc[df["pos"] == "GK"].loc[df["goals"].isnull()].loc[:,"goals"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

The first line selects the index and you know the column, so just use one `loc` and it should be fine:

`df.loc[(df["pos"] == "GK") & (df["goals"].isnull()), 'goals'].fillna(0, inplace=True)`

## update:

So it seems pandas returns a copy and `inplace` doesn't really do anything there. However, you don't want to assign it to all of your dataframe.
Since you are already filtering for nan values, an easier way is to just assign the value directly.
`df.loc[(df["pos"] == "GK") & (df["goals"].isnull()), 'goals'] = 0`
This worked fine on my computer, hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I didn't work :( It runs but when I then review the dataframe it doesn't seem to have affected the NaN values.

Comment: Can you link the database you are using?

Comment: I am using the squads.csv from here: https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/tree/master/data/2019/2019-07-09

Comment: it worked! Thank you so much, I was so confused but your update makes a lot of sense as to the best way of applying the number.

Comment: the updated one worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
df[(df["pos"] == "GK") & (df["goals"].isnull()), 'goals']=0
```

That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You already masked using a boolean select. So just `.fillna(0)`

```
df[(df["pos"] == "GK") & (df["goals"].isnull())].fillna(0)
```